# Ubuntu 22.04 switching between dual displays/single display

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I connect my Ubuntu 22.04 PC to 2 monitors A and B and set it to "Join Displays" mode. Then I switch monitor A to another input source (e.g., a Windows PC). However, the Ubuntu still displays in dual screen mode, and the windows displayed in monitor A before become invisible. I have to manually change to single display mode in gnome settings to make it work.

Is there any way to make Ubuntu automatically switched to single display mode after a monitor is connected to another source?